# How to match X and Y coordinates from a click inside a button with the corresponding bitmap pixels (C# Windows Store Apps)?

Tags: c#, button, bitmap, windows-store-apps, pixel

I have a button with some image as its content. I attach `PointerEntered` event handler to the button and get `PointerPoint` coordinates when the cursor enters the button. I can get the bitmap of the button content using `RenderTargetBitmap` and get an `array` of pixels from that `bitmap`. I need to find the exact pixel corresponding to the `PointerPoint` location to check it for transparency.

Here is the code:

```
public async void button_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap;
    bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(button);

    IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

    Pointer pointer = e.Pointer;
    PointerPoint ppt = e.GetCurrentPoint(button);

}
```

I have `ppt.X` and `ppt.Y`, how to I find the corresponding pixel in pixels array?

Answer (score 0):

to access a certain 2d pixel in a 1d array the offset would be x + y * width where width is the width of the image